# Will excel refresh its data via web query if the sheet is currently open?

Tags: excel

In this example from  [pulling into excel from yahoo finance](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/pull-data-into-microsoft-excel-with-web-queries/)

under Data Range Properties, there is an option to refresh data every so often. Now, will this keep refreshing the data if the excel sheet is open/closed? My guess is if I open the excel sheet,it cannot be refreshed, but could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will ***ONLY*** refresh while the workbook is *OPEN*